# JavaFX: Change cursor visibility, but in how cursor interacts "on-hover"

Tags: java, javafx

I have found that it is possible to change the mouse cursor by using the `.setCursor()` method on the scene you'd like to affect. You can even change the mouse to be invisible by doing `scene.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);`

However, when the mouse hovers over a node that changes the cursor's appearance, it reappears because the other image (the hand or resize-arrows) is being drawn.

### Is there some way I can programatically  force the cursor's image to not change when it hovers over something, like the slider in a SplitPane, or the TitledPane of an Accordion?

I have provided a minimal example of an accordion with an invisible cursor so you can easily see what it looks like. When you get to the TitledPane, the cursor goes from being invisible to being a hand.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;


public class Main extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        Accordion accordion = new Accordion
        (
                new TitledPane("TitledPane #1", new Label("Content #1"))
        );

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(accordion, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for any time or interest invested into my question.

Comment: The title region has its cursor set in code. You should be able to override this using CSS via [`-fx-cursor`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node). Properties set by an "author stylesheet" [have a higher priority](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/css/StyleableProperty.html) then when set by code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand the info provided, but I'm missing an important piece of information. Is it possible to edit the "author stylesheet" by code? I only want the cursor to ignore `:hover` changes under certain conditions (or I want to be able to turn the effect on/off). Thanks so much for the helpful information.

Comment: You could subclass `TitledPane`, for example, and give it a `BooleanProperty` which internally (de)activates a `PseudoClass`. Then target the `TitledPane`, possibly with your own style class, using something like: `.titled-pane:no-cursor > .title { -fx-cursor: none; }`. Another option is to add a style class to a `TitledPane` only when you want no cursor, but as this is an on-off thing a pseudo class seems more appropriate. Note, I don't believe you _need_ to subclass in order to use a custom pseudo class, but it does encapsulate it better.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I'll try that tonight when I get home. Will report back with results.

Comment: Sorry for the massive delay, but I had trouble getting this to work unfortunately, although I appreciate all the help. I'm just writing this to explain why I haven't answered this question yet.